# Which one of these parents' children is/are you?

Tags: word-order

It seems to me that the two are correct.

> 1 Which one of these parents’ children is you?

(My interlocuter is looking at a picture with parents and children and wants to know which one is me.)

> 2 Which one of these parents’ child are you?

You are these parents' child. - Which parents' child are you? - Which one of these parents' child are you?

Am I correct or wrong on all this?

Comment: The expression "parents' children" is very odd.  All children are children of parents. It's an odd thing to say.

Comment: The sentence is not "parents' children" but  "Which one of these parents’ children".

Answer (score 2):

The question "Which one of these parents' children are you?" and "...is you" are both possible.  The difficulty arises because both these sentences are correct:

> You are James.
> James is you.

In those sentences it is easy to identify the subject. But it is less easy in your sentence.  It is unclear if the subject of the question is "Which one... chidren" or "you", and I think it could be parsed both ways.  I prefer the "are you" form with "you" as the subject, by analogy with the simpler sentence "Who are you?"

The question as phrased is odd, since "parents' children" is a strange combination of words. The word "parents'" is not needed since all children are the children of their parents.  There is no such thing as a child who isn't a "parents' child" (even if their parents are unknown or deceased).

If you are asking someone to identify themselves just use

> Which one of these children are you?

or perhaps more simply

> Where are you (in this photo)?

Your comment tells me that you actually want the person to identify their **parents** and not themselves.  For this your question is wrong. It doesn't mean what you think it means.

If you want the person to identify themselves and their parents then use two questions (as you want two answers)

> Where are you in this photo, and who are your parents?

Or if you only want the parents:

> Where are your parents in this photo?

or

> Are your parents in this photo? (more natural, since if you can't identify the parents, you can't tell for certain if they are there at all.)

It would be more natural in a dialogue:

> Look at this photo of my 8th birthday party.
> Oh that's cute. Where are you?
> I'm the one with the green hat.
> Is that your dad standing behind you?
> No Mum and Dad are on the right.  Mum is wearing the red jumper...

Comment: Vote up! But I still don't agree that the question is strange. A possible situation: There is a group of parents (couples) and I want to know the parents of a certain child. Take heed, by the way, that it was "child" not "children" in 2. Still appreciate the answer.

Comment: Your question doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: which one of the two do you mean?

Comment: All of them.  The all ask about "child" or "children" and don't ask anything about "parents"

Comment: James "Which one of these children are you?" is grammatically wrong. Would you say "Which one of these children like you?" or "Which one of these children likes you?"

Comment: Thanks,  for your comment,  perhaps you could answer the question yourself.

Comment: Perhaps, but it's not the point. The point is whether my comment is correct or not. If you just want to aggrandize yourself then I am not taking part in it. If you want to sort out the issue then let's leave out sulky sentiments.

Comment: No.  I disagree with you.  But that's fine.  The analogy with "likes you" is good but imperfect since the verb "is" is a linking verb, not a transitive verb.  That makes a difference to question construction. However you asked a question; I attempted to answer it; you say my answer is wrong.  If my answer is wrong, and you know the correct answer, you can self answer the question.  That's encouraged here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115492/discussion-between-user1425-and-james-k).